# mqtt node-red iot platfform

Tags: mqtt, iot, node-red

Read an event from a device in Watson IoTPlatform using [node-red](https://nodered.org/docs/) and occur following error `missing broker configuration`

Request Data

```
[{"id":"e045d0f1.7d3b6","type":"mqtt in","z":"128ab415.c6150c","name":"DHT22_001","topic":"iot-2/type/DHT22/id/DTH22001/evt/data/fmt/json","qos":"2","broker":"3a8caa38.c01576","x":162,"y":99,"wires":[["dd729941.33d4e8"]]},{"id":"dd729941.33d4e8","type":"debug","z":"128ab415.c6150c","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":421,"y":99,"wires":[]},{"id":"3a8caa38.c01576","type":"mqtt-broker","z":"","broker":"s16hxe.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com","port":"1883","clientid":"d:s16hxe:DHT22:DHT22_001","usetls":false,"compatmode":true,"keepalive":"60","cleansession":true,"willTopic":"","willQos":"0","willPayload":"","birthTopic":"","birthQos":"0","birthPayload":""}]
```

Comment: Share your code where you got the error

Comment: As error is self explanatory. Configure your `MQTT ` broker. Follow this link to configuration - https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/config-nodes